# Trouble providing data sets with package

Tags: r, package

I have two data sets `full` and `raw` that I placed in the `data/` directory of my package. However, when I load my package, they are not available. I tried looking for them using the `data` function, but did not see them.

```
data(raw, package = "pkg")
```

> Warning message:
>   In data(raw, package = "pkg") : data set 'raw' not found

Do I have to export them somehow?

I noticed when I tried to open the file using `load` from another computer, it read in as a string. Maybe I'm not writing the data frame properly? I used:

```
save(df.full, file = "full.RData")
save(df.raw, file = "raw.RData")
```

Comment: Hmm, generally what you do looks correct... just for reference, did you have a look at [the corresponding chapter in hadley's book](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/data.html) and [this section in the R manual](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html#Data-in-packages)? Generally, data sets are exported automatically. Did you do `data(package = "pkg")` to make sure they don't have another name or something?

Comment: I was actually saving a tbl_df instead of a data.frame.

Comment: ...which shouldn't matter?

Comment: No, it did matter since a `tbl_df` is a list.

Comment: @wdkrnls a data frame is a list too. And in an R package, "data" can refer to any R object.